# redirect "about author" code to about page

Tags: redirect, author, links, profiles

I'd like to redirect/change this code

```
<a href='" . $wp_about_author_author['posts_url']. "' title='". $wp_about_author_author['name'] ."'>". 
   apply_filters( 'wp_about_author_name', $wp_about_author_author['name'] ) ."
</a>
```

So instead of the link from the author's profile ( at the bottom of his blog entry) going to the author's list of blog posts, the link goes to the author's about/profile page

[Here's](https://www.absolutept.com/short-foot-exercise-for-flat-feet/) the blog page

I've tried

```
<a href='" . $wp_about_author_author['user_url']. "' title='". $wp_about_author_author['name'] ."'>". 
  apply_filters( 'wp_about_author_name', $wp_about_author_author['name'] ) ."
</a>
```

but no luck

Comment: What does `$wp_about_author_author` look like?

Comment: Use `print_r($wp_about_author_author);` and check if there is any index for `user_url`

Comment: $wp_about_author_author['posts_url'] = get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'));

Answer (score 1):

Use get_userdata() to retrieve all user data. The function accepts user ID. So the following code will give you the user url.

```
<?php
   php $user_info = get_userdata(1); /* replace 1 with dynamic user id variable in your context*/
   echo 'User url: ' . $user_info->user_url . "\n";
   echo 'Users name: ' . $user_info->first_name . "\n";
?>
```